# how to apply validation on date matching in python regex

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

s = "hello,2021/11/54, world"

ans = re.search('[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}' ,s)


if ans is None:
    print("no match")
else:
    print(ans.group())
```

i want to match date from the given string but i does not want to match for months value greater than 12 and day value greater than 31 how to do this so far i have tried this and it works perfectly fine.
**date is in format YYYY/MM/DD**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using regex only to extract the various date candidates in your text.  Other than this, rely on the `datetime` library to check the validity of the date.

```py
import datetime
import re

def validate(date_text):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y/%m/%d')
        print(date_text + " => VALID")
    except ValueError:
        print(date_text + " => INVALID date format, should be YYYY/MM/DD")

s = "hello,2021/11/54, world"
dates = re.findall(r'\b\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}\b', s)
for date in dates:
    validate(date)
```

The reason to avoid pure regex is that there are a number of edge cases which can be difficult to accurately capture.  For example, February may have 28 or 29 days, depending on whether or not it be a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

To search for the date, use the following regex command: `(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}[-\\/ ]?(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[-/ ]?(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])`

The following code should work:

```py
import re

s = "hello,2021/11/54, world"

ans = re.search('(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}[-\\/ ]?(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[-/ ]?(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])' ,s)


if ans is None:
    print("no match")
else:
    print(ans.group())
```

*Note: The date range is only from 1900 - 2999*